# how to display ajax loading image

Tags: jquery

I want to show ajax loading image. but don't know how to do that. here is my working ajax script. please help me 
to integrate ajax loading gif.thanks

```
$(function() { 
    $( "#slider" ).slider({ 
       stop: function(event, ui) {
              $.ajax({
              url: "ajax.php",
              cache: false,
              async: false,
             data: "",
                  success: function(html){
                $("#result_list").html(html);
              }
            });

         }
    });
});
```

Comment: You should consider making your request asynchronous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(function() { 
$( "#slider" ).slider({ 
   stop: function(event, ui) {
          $("#place_of_loading_image").show();
          $.ajax({
          url: "ajax.php",
          cache: false,
          async: false,
          data: "",
          success: function(html){ //got the data

            $("#place_of_loading_image").hide(); // hide ajax loader         
            $("#result_list").html(html);        // show downloaded content
          }
        });

     }
    });
});
```

Where  **#place_of_loading_image** is some container (like **div**), in a place you would like loader.gif to appear.

```
<div id="place_of_loading_image" style="display:none"><img src="load.gif"/></div>
```

Comment: this script is working fine in firefox. but not in opera,chrome, ie. please help me thanks

Comment: I edited the post. With this variant you can first remove 'style="display:none"' and see that this image is correctly displayed for all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at blockui?
http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

```
$(function() { 
    $( "#slider" ).slider({ 
       stop: function(event, ui) {
          $.blockUI({ message: null });  //loading
              $.ajax({
              url: "ajax.php",
              cache: false,
              async: false,
             data: "",
                  success: function(html){
                  $.unblockUI(); //loading complete
                $("#result_list").html(html);
              }
            });

         }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ajax have api ajax start and ajax stop, when ever an ajax request is send this apis triggers

```
 $(document).bind("ajaxStart.mine", function() {
      $("#image").html("<img src="loading.gif"/>");
    });

$(document).bind("ajaxStop.mine", function() {
  $("#image").html("");
});
```

Show and Hide your image using classes.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start your XHR, show the loading image.

On the success callback of your XHR, hide the loading image.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will help.

At start of your function:

```
jQuery('#processing').html( '<img src="/images/ajaxBigFlower.gif">' );
$('#submit').attr("disabled", true);
```

In success part of your function:

```
jQuery('#processing').html( '' );
$('#submit').attr("disabled", false);
```

**Note:** `<div id='processing'></div>` should be in your HTML and you can set the position of this DIV anywhere on page using css. And set `id='submit'` for these submit buttons that you want to set as disabled when it is processing...