# .load() image loading gif

Tags: jquery

I am loading content dynamically using .load() i want to display a loading image (.gif) to show the user that something is happening.

How would i achieve this with the below code?

```
$('#prac_slider li a').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('class') != 'active') {
        $('#prac_slider li a').removeClass('active').animate({ "opacity" : 0.5 });
        $(this).addClass('active').animate({ "opacity" : 1 });
        var $permalink = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#practitioner').fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $(this).load($permalink + ' #pracLoad',function(){
            $(this).fadeIn();
        })
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to display ajax loading image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134110/how-to-display-ajax-loading-image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might just want to do something like

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){ 
    $('#AJAXload').show(); 
}).ajaxStop(function(){ 
    $('#AJAXload').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add a style to your css file

```
.hidden {display:none;}
```

and now use in your jquery code as follows

```
$('#prac_slider li a').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('class') != 'active') {
        $('#loadingimage').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#prac_slider li a').removeClass('active').animate({ "opacity" : 0.5 });
        $(this).addClass('active').animate({ "opacity" : 1 });
        var $permalink = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#practitioner').fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $(this).load($permalink + ' #pracLoad',function(){
            $(this).fadeIn();
        })
        $('#loadingimage').addClass('hidden');
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

and finally have a image like this

```
<img src=""images/loading.gif" class="hidden" id="loadingimage" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(){
// Handle the beforeSend event
    $('#loading').show();
},
    complete: function(){
    // Handle the complete event
    $('#loading').hide();
    }
    //DO STUFF
});
```